# Zooming and cropping an image (either taken form camera or gallery)

Tags: android-studio

So I want to be able to zoom and crop an image which has either just been take from a photo or has been selected from the gallery.

I found this library so far:

https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

I don't really know how to add this library to my project though. So I set about importing the project from github, getting it compile, and then adding it to my project manually somehow.

Unfortunately I have not been able to get it to work. I was initially using Gradle 4.10.1. On Gradle 4.10.1 I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedModuleVersionResult'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Doing those suggestions does not help. I also tried downgrading to earlier versions of gradle like version 1.9, but then was getting other errors:

```
ERROR: Could not determine the class-path for class com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.ng.SyncAction.
```

Any ideas on either how to get this library working, or alternatives for crop and zoom welcome. Basically the user takes a photo with their camera (already got this working) and then I immediately want to pass it to something so they can crop and zoom it and then use it in the app. Same for after they select a photo from gallery (got this part working too), I'll send them to be able to crop and zoom it.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The library you are using is not way to import this easily. The only option is to get the java file from the git hub project copy in to you project..
but i suggest you yo use this link this is a library who have multiple function about the crop and selection of image.

## https://github.com/igreenwood/SimpleCropView

Comment: thanks man. in the end i got a recommendatnio and used this one : https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper